# Making a dynamic {{ siteUrl }} for local mobile testing

Tags: templating, multi-environment, siteurl

I'm developing a site using a mobile first approach, connecting the phone via USB and using Safari's Web Inspector on iOS8.

On my local machine, the url for all CSS, JS and href links is `http://localhost:8888/` (running MAMP) but on the phone it's my IP or `http://00.00.00.00:8888/`

Right now, this issue is breaking the entire site when testing on a device. All links are broken.

How can I make the Craft variable `{{ siteUrl }}`... well variable?

Answer (score 3):

Hey Jeremy you can actually make siteUrl work using [Multi-Enviroment Configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) and your general.php file will end up looking something like this.

```
return array(
'*' => array(
    // ...
),

'example.dev' => array(
    // ...

    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => '/users/brandon/Sites/example.dev/public/',
        'baseUrl'  => 'http://example.dev/',
    )
),

'example.com' => array(
    // ...

    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => '/storage/av12345/www/public_html/',
        'baseUrl'  => 'http://example.com/',
    )
)
```

);

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal in all situations, but one option is to simply set the Site URL to `/`:

[image: Site URL]

This should make all your links relative, rather than absolute.

Comment: Hey Steve, I don't suppose you have the code that was in that link? It's a busted link now, making this answer kinda worthless. :(

Comment: Hey Lindsey, no code to speak of, just putting a forward slash into the Site URL field in General Settings. You may run into issues with this solution though, I'd recommend considering Adam's multi-environment set up as a better solution. The slash is a quick fix though and I do have a lot of sites running with that set up.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I added the image directly to the answer, so we can be certain that it stays there forever. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the USB solution and just access your MAMP installation directly over your local network, you can also use a program called SquidMan (which is GUI wrapper for Squid) to set up a local network proxy. Here are [detailed instructions](http://benjaminrojas.net/view-mamp-virtual-hosts-on-your-ipad-and-iphone-over-the-local-network/), but the basics are:

- Download and launch SquidMan
- Change the MAMP port to just use the default 80 to avoid many of the environment port config issues.
- Set your MAMP hosts IP address to your local machine address (which should be available in the 'IP Address' dropdown under the hosts tab).
- Start both MAMP server and Squid (via SquidMan)
- Set the phone to use the squid proxy, then access the site normally through your phone using the MAMP address (i.e. http://sitename.craft.dev)